# Make mysql client use ALL_PROXY socks5 server

Tags: proxy, mysql-cli

I want to connect to an aurora serverless database from my local machine. Because the database is only accessible from within the aws cloud, I have setup an ec2 instance running [microsocks](https://github.com/rofl0r/microsocks):

```
./microsocks -p 8888
```

I now want to connect using mysql from my machine:

```
export ALL_PROXY=socks5h://xx.xx.xx.xx:8888

mysql --user=admin --password=XXXX -h database-XXXX.cluster-XXXX.eu-XXXX.rds.amazonaws.com
```

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'database...com' (111)

If I run this command on the ec2 instance it succeeds. So I assume that mysql does not respect my proxy settings. If I run curl on my machine it respects the proxy settings.

Note that this is just for testing purposes and I know that this would not be a solution for production use.

Answer (score 0):

You may use proxychains.

```sh
yum install  proxychains-ng
```

edit config file `/etc/proxychains.conf`, and add this:

```sh
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks5  {your proxy.address} {your.proxy.port}
```

Lastly, you can run mysql like this:

```sh
proxychains mysql --user=admin --password=XXXX -h database-XXXX.cluster-XXXX.eu-XXXX.rds.amazonaws.com
```